# MySQL wont start on boot after upgrading to 15.04

Tags: boot, 15.04, mysql

I recently rebuilt my server and decided to **upgrade from 14.04 LTS to 15.04**. I can't seem to figure out why MySQl won't start on boot. I have ran the following command.

```
sudo update-rc.d mysql defaults
```

It doesn't seem to do anything.

When I first boot up my server. I have to run `sudo services mysql stop`, then `sudo servies mysql start` for it to work.

It seems like its trying to start on boot but getting hung somewhere. Need help to get MySQl to start on boot for ubuntu 15.04